# How can I get Eclipse File Search to skip certain files?

Tags: eclipse, search

In my Eclipse project, I have a mixture of java files, xml, and various files with different file extensions. I want to perform searches on a regular basis on everything except for the java files, to look for certain settings.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to search all the files, EXCEPT the one's with a .java extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding file types in Eclipse / Aptana find in files search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242982/excluding-file-types-in-eclipse-aptana-find-in-files-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do inside the file search dialog is to press the button "Choose" for the "File name patterns", then press "select all" and deselect "*.java".

But beware! This doesn't look for all file extensions in your project and lists them. It's a predefined set of extensions.

Comment: so you're saying checking _all_ of the boxes could result in a different set of files being considered than checking _none_ of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your file search dialog, there is a "Choose" button next to the "file name patterns" textbox. It allows you to filter Select Types. After selection, you should just realize it is just regex of everything except for *.java.